# How do I print a 10 first items on a Array List

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

My ArrayList has 100 rows, but I want to display only the first 10 entries. Maybe someone will find out how to do it?

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray devices = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

                for (int i = 0; i < devices.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = devices.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String known = c.getString("known");
                    String description = c.getString("description");
                    String controllerId = c.getString("controllerId");


                    JSONObject frequencySurvey = c.getJSONObject("frequencySurvey");
                    if (frequencySurvey.has("5000")) {
                        JSONObject fivezero = frequencySurvey.getJSONObject("5000");

                        String timestamp = fivezero.getString("timestamp");
                        String clients = fivezero.getString("clients");
                        String enabled = fivezero.getString("enabled");

                        HashMap<String, String> device = new HashMap<>();

                        device.put("id", id);
                        device.put("name", name);
                        device.put("enabled", enabled);
                        device.put("clients", clients);

                        DevicesList.add(device);

                    }
                }
            }

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Devices_5_0.this, DevicesList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "name","clients","enabled"},
                new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.clients, enabled});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

On Create:

```
DevicesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Global declare:

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DevicesList;
```

In no way can I limit my list in advance

Answer (score 0):

You add a for-loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (yourArray.size() <= 10 ? yourArray.size() : 10); i++){
    //Add to another list, or do something to store these entries
}

//Display them, print them, whatever you need
```

It prints up to 10 of the first entries. This system is in place to prevent exceptions if the array's size < 10. If there are less than 10 objects, it displays them all.

Comment: I would suggest `Math.min(10, yourArray.size())` instead for slightly improved readability.

Answer (score 0):

If your `devices` JSONArray size is greater than `10` then just parse JSONObject  only for `first 10` entries.

**Try this:**

```
       try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            JSONArray devices = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

            int limit = devices.length();
            if (limit > 10) 
                limit = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                JSONObject c = devices.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String name = c.getString("name");
                String known = c.getString("known");
                String description = c.getString("description");
                String controllerId = c.getString("controllerId");


                JSONObject frequencySurvey = c.getJSONObject("frequencySurvey");
                if (frequencySurvey.has("5000")) {
                    JSONObject fivezero = frequencySurvey.getJSONObject("5000");

                    String timestamp = fivezero.getString("timestamp");
                    String clients = fivezero.getString("clients");
                    String enabled = fivezero.getString("enabled");

                    HashMap<String, String> device = new HashMap<>();

                    device.put("id", id);
                    device.put("name", name);
                    device.put("enabled", enabled);
                    device.put("clients", clients);

                    DevicesList.add(device);

                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this will help~